# Regular Expression to capture phrase only when it follows a certain phrase

Tags: regex

For this example, say I want to capture the word "Dog", but only when it follows the word "Red", so for this:

```
The Red Dog was a Dog.
```

I would want to capture the first "Dog"

However for this:

```
The Dog was a Red Dog.
```

I would only want to capture the 2nd Dog.

I feel like this isnt that hard, I'm just blanking and can't find it anywhere.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use lookbehind for this:

```
(?<=Red )\bDog\b
```

Here `(?<=Red )` is **positive lookbehind**, that means match `Dog` only when it is preceded by `"Red "`

#### [RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/bN1jI8/1)

Comment: A positive lookbehind is a little overkill.  You could also just use a capture group: `\bRed (Dog)\b`